# Text Input and filter in Yii FrameWork

Tags: php, yii

How can I create a new TextInput and make it a filterSelector in Yii framework
I had made this in the model :

```
<input name='searchfield' id='searchModel'> 

'filterSelector' => '#searchModel',
```

and for the searchModel :

```
if ($this->company_name) {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'company_name', $this->company_name]);;
 }
```

but the problem is that the gridview is refreshing without showing the results

Comment: are you using CActiveDataProvider or CArrrayDataProvider? Are you supplying filter to it in the controller? [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/232/using-filters-with-cgridview-and-carraydataprovider/) is a useful link.

Comment: Hi Peaceman Thank you for your answer but unfortunally this is not what I'm looking for, let me explain it to you , I'm testing the Advanced application ( presented on the Yiiframework website ) and I have all the code is already generated but the problem is when I had to add a new TextInput and try to search and filter with it using an ActiveDataProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged this as Yii, but from the syntax it's probably Yii2. I'm going to give you something I worked on:

This would be your controller:

```
public function actionSomething()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

    if(isset($_GET['query']))
    {
        $query = $_GET['query'];
        $criteria->compare('attribute_of_model', $query, true, 'OR');
        // you can add more attributes with which you want to compare query, that is why I added 'OR' if you remove 'OR' it defaults to 'AND'
    }
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider("YourModel", array('criteria'=>$criteria));

        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
}
```

And this would be your view:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="search" placeholder="filter" name="query" value="<?=isset($_GET['query']) ? CHtml::encode($_GET['query']) : '' ; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

This should work. If you are developing Yii2 then you will have to alter it slightly.